# Terraform import service in azure from module

Tags: import, terraform

I have created a service in Azure manually, and need to import this into the state file of my configuration. However, I get a syntax error when running the `terraform import` command.

```
terraform import -var-file="../../input/env/ssa/terraform-ssa-SSASTORAGE.json" 'module.management.azurerm_storage_account.main[\"ssaautomation"\]' /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/SSASTORAGE/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/ssaautomation
```

Error:

```
The import command expects two arguments.
```

The way I see it, I'm running the command with two arguments in powershell
I have executed this command before with no issue - does anyone why I get the following error?

NOTE: The single brackets on the module part of the code is due to the fact that I'm running in powershell. Ref. this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html).

Comment: The `"` should not be escaped, but I am unsure if that will completely fix the issue.

Comment: See the link i posted above. Terraform recommends to use " in their documentation for powershell.

Answer (score 0):

There were some syntax error:

My code:

```
'module.management.azurerm_storage_account.main[\"ssaautomation"\]'
```

**"\** - needed to switch place

Fix:

```
'module.management.azurerm_storage_account.main[\"ssaautomation\"]'
```